# fetch all nested resources by resource id on a many to many relationship

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I want to create a NestJs API with TypeORM and have two entities, **users** and **groups**. A User can join multiple groups and a group can have multiple users.

I created these ORM models for the user

```
@Entity('User')
export class UserEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  // ...

  @ManyToMany((type: any) => GroupEntity, (group: GroupEntity) => group.users)
  @JoinTable()
  groups: GroupEntity[];
}
```

and for the group

```
@Entity('Group')
export class GroupEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  // ...

  @ManyToMany((type: any) => UserEntity, (user: UserEntity) => user.groups)
  @JoinTable()
  users: UserEntity[];
}
```

When calling the route `GET localhost:3000/users/1/groups` I want to return an array of groups the user belongs to. The **UsersService** executes this

```
const groups: GroupEntity[] = await this.groupsRepository.find({
  where: { userId: 1 },
  relations: ['users'],
});
```

When calling the route `GET localhost:3000/groups/1/users` I want to return an array of users the group is holding. The **GroupsService** executes this

```
const users: UserEntity[] = await this.usersRepository.find({
  where: { groupId: 1 },
  relations: ['groups'],
});
```

Unfortunately both endpoints return every nested subresource. It seems the `where` clause gets ignored. The database creates two cross tables

[image]

but I would expect only one cross table because one of them is redundant, no?. Of course this can have technical reasons. What is the correct way to fetch the subresources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### First Problem

In TypeORM when you define `@ManyToMany` relation you need to use `@JoinTable` on one (owning) side of relation.

So in this way, it will create only one cross table.

Example

```
@Entity('User')
export class UserEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  // ...

  @ManyToMany((type: any) => GroupEntity, (group: GroupEntity) => group.users)
  @JoinTable()
  groups: GroupEntity[];
}

@Entity('Group')
export class GroupEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  // ...

  @ManyToMany((type: any) => UserEntity, (user: UserEntity) => user.groups)
  users: UserEntity[];
}
```

`It will generate three tables users, groups, and user_groups_group`

### Second Problem

You can use this query

```
user = await userRepo.find({
    relations: ['groups'],
    where: { id: user.id }
});
const groups = user.groups
```

And as your code suggests that you are using Lazy loading of `typeORM`, so you can do this

```
const user = await userRepo.find({
    where: { id: someId }
});
const groups = await note.groups
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. So If I got you right I removed the `@JoinTable()` from the `GroupEntity` and went for this query https://hatebin.com/pfiqqysjzi and do the same for the groups service?